# Extract complete Data from API using python into Json format

Tags: python, json, asynchronous

I want to extract the data using API and store the data into Json format.

```
Code:
def run():
    responses = asyncio.run(fetch_all())
    return responses
output = run()
count = int(output[0]['result']['stats']['count'])
print(count)
import time
async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        resp = await response.json()
        return resp
async def fetch_all():
    limit = 100
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(auth=aiohttp.BasicAuth('***','***')) as session:
        tasks = []
        for i in range(int(count/limit) + 1):
            tasks.append(
                fetch(
                    session,
                    f"https:XYZ&sysparm_limit={limit}&sysparm_offset={i*limit}",
                )
            )
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        return responses
def run():
    start = time.time()
    responses = asyncio.run(fetch_all())
    end = time.time()
    return {"responses":responses, "time_duration":end- start}
sap_prod = run()
final_output = []
for i in range(len(sap_prod['responses'])):
   final_output = final_output +sap_prod['responses'][i]['result']
    
json_object = json.dumps(final_output, indent = 4)
```

Error:

TypeError: 'ClientPayloadError' object is not subscriptable

Data is huge so my IDE is crashing, How can I dump the output into a Json using loops?
Also suggest any alternate method to get complete data from APIs

Answer (score 0):

In fetch you can write the data to a file, producing a line-delimited json file

```py
async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        resp = await response.json()
        with open('myfile.jsonl', 'a') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(resp) + '\n')
```

The way after all of the tasks are done you will have a file with many json lines in it, to read it you can do

```py
data = []
with open('myfile.jsonl') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: Updated the fetch function, and updated below at the end of fetchall(), but still can't get the output. Got 604 records, but should get 60492
data = []
    with open('myfile.jsonl') as f:
        for line in f:
            data.append(json.loads(line))
    print(len(data))

Comment: This sounds like each line contains 1000 rows, try this after reading the data `from itertools import chain`, `data = list(chain.from_iterable(data))`

Comment: data = []
with open('myfile.jsonl') as f:
   for line in f:
       data.append(json.loads(line))

from itertools import chain
data = list(chain.from_iterable(data))
print(len(data))
Used above: the count changed to 614